# Paraxial Rays and Coma

Tags: optics, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, lenses

In [these slides](https://www.slideshare.net/VineetPanwar4/lens-aberrations-physics-term-paper) it is stated that:

> Coma is an abberration that afflicts off-axis light bundles in a
> similar manner to the way in which spherical aberrations affects the
> axial bundles.

About Coma, my questions are:

**1)** Does it appear mathematically even in paraxial optics with spherical lens? Or does it just appear when non-paraxial optics is considered (just like spherical aberration)?

**2)** Suppose you have the ideal surface for a convex lens, i.e. an hyperboloid surface. It does not show spherical aberration. Will it show coma?

Comment: The policy of this SE is that you should try to avoid several questions in a single post. I suggest that you ask the question on field curvature in a separate post.

Comment: Ok I'll ask in a second question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coma is a so-called "3rd order aberration" of off-axis rays entering at a relatively "large" angle, hence is beyond the paraxial approximation. How large the actual angle maybe is context dependent but one of the most frequently cited and used criterion is Abbe's "sine condition" which is a necessary condition for nulling what is called "primary coma", see [Abbe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abbe_sine_condition).

A spherical lens has no "primary coma", it trivially satisfies Abbe's sine condition but has spherical aberration. Large angle optical scanning is always achieved with the system satisfying the sine condition, this is necessary but not sufficient to achieve stigmatic imaging as there are always other aberrations too. Practical examples for systems nulling 3rd order aberrations and beyond are the Schwarzschild, Ritchey-Chretien, etc., and similar two-mirror telescopes.

A hyperboloid refractor surface by itself, I guess you are referring to cartesian oval in the limit, has yuuuuuge coma, for it cannot satisfy the sine condition if it has a finite size. That does not mean that a hyperbolic surface cannot be part of low coma system. For example it can be and is used as a secondary mirror with a primary parabolic mirror, and the combination of the two, the so-called Cassegrain telescope, has much less coma than a simple parabolic mirror would have by itself.

Comment: About the hyperboloid refractor, I can't understand the reason for why it should have coma, as its equation is found by setting that all input rays (even tilted) should meet at the same time in one point of focus. If it has finite size, won't the outer rays simply going out from the refractor?

Comment: The hyperboloid refractor refracts at its surface that is not spherical and does not satisfy, therefore, Abbe's sine condition. Of course, a hyperboloid being a quadratic surface if the aperture around the axis is small then so will be the aberrations resulting from lack of spherical symmetry. Note that it has only one pair foci. Any ray  not going through one of these foci (one is in the infinity in the direction of the axis, hence, not parallel with the hyperboloid's axis) is not refracted through the other focus. So it has all kinds of aberrations except for the spherical one.